# Firefox linear-gradient issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, gradient

I've got a gradient div, here it is:

```
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

And here is css:

```
.gradient {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, #fff 100%)
}
```

Very simple.
In Chrome it's works fine, but in Firefox (34.0, Ubuntu 14.04) it's work not correctly:
[image: Firefox gradient screenshot]

I tried use `rgba(0,0,0,0)` instead `transparent`, tried `-moz-linear-gradient` prefix — no results.

[dabblet link](http://dabblet.com/gist/13ae5288b8f0178f8d38)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 White to Transparent Gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647305/css3-white-to-transparent-gradient)

Comment: Have you looked at [this?](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid the grey in the middle you can use a gradient from transparent white `(255, 255, 255, 0)` to opaque white `(255, 255, 255, 1),#fff`.

```
.gradient {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, #fff 100%)
}
```

http://dabblet.com/gist/64dd43f37e8978d08749

In your code the gradient goes from transparent black to opaque white and because of that the grey part in the middle shows up in FF.

I guess chrome and other browser calculate the color steps in the gradient differently.