# Website looks different in different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am testing my website and I noticed that in Safari it looks different to Chrome and Mozila. Checked my html and css in validator and it all seems fine, so not sure why is this happening.

I validated html and css and found 1 mistake in HTML and 3 in CSS, although its a first attempt so its messy, i think, but what could make this happening?

Bellow is banner's css, can this linear gradient affect it?

Guys I'm total noob, its my first ever attempt, so when answer, please speak english language first of all, and than code-language :).

```
    .main-header {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  height: 750px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(0deg, whitesmoke, transparent 70%, rgba(200,216,239,1)),
  url('../img/MainGib.jpeg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image] 
[image]

Comment: just a guess, change the gradient to: `linear-gradient(0deg, whitesmoke, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%, ...` [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647305/css3-white-to-transparent-gradient)

Comment: after putting 0 at the end of rgba it removed the shade from the h1 and h2, but still it looks different, like more smoked than white hehe....

Comment: I did not meant, that you should to change the existing rgba(). Try to throw out the `transparent` keyword, to make it look like this: `linear-gradient(0deg, whitesmoke, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%, rgba(200,216,239,1)),
  url('../img/MainGib.jpeg') no-repeat center;`

Comment: Thats worked! Sorry, I didn't read carefuly your first comment. Thanks a lot Nico, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you might have to add css for -moz and -webkit:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, whitesmoke, transparent 70%, rgba(200,216,239,1)),
  url('../img/MainGib.jpeg') no-repeat center;
-moz-linear-gradient(0deg, whitesmoke, transparent 70%, rgba(200,216,239,1)),
  url('../img/MainGib.jpeg') no-repeat center;
```

Comment: thanks for this, but this removed this linear gradient from the image. looks like gradient 0deg here goes from left to right? Very confused.

Comment: Do you have a link to the dev site ?

Comment: No Scot, sorry, I'm doing it in the brackets, not sure i can share it, right?